# Visual Studio editor - extend selection to the next larger code block?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio 2010, is there any way to quickly extend the selected text to the next logical code block?   For example, if my cursor was here:

[image: location of cursor]

And I hit some magical keyboard shortcut, it would select the entire string:

[image: Example of selected string]

Hit it again, and it would select the next larger logical block of code:

[image: Example of selected code block]

And so on.   Does this exist?  My google-fu seems to be failing me..

Comment: CTRL + ALT + RIGHT / CTRL + ALT + LEFT do the magic. It is a must!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Visual Studio 2017 15.5.2 has this feature built-in after it was first [hinted at in a Visual Studio 2017 Preview blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2017/11/20/overview-of-visual-studio-2017-updates-for-net-developers/) (see section "Smart Code Editor").

Invoking it can be done by going to `Edit > Advanced > Expand Selection` or by binding the `Edit.ExpandSelection` command to <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>=</kbd> (actually the default if you start without any previous keybindings).

Shrinking / contracting the selection is possible as well, look for `Edit > Advanced > Contract Selection` or the `Edit.ContractSelection` command (default <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> ).

Comment: My default shortcuts (15.9.16) are `Shift+Alt+=` and `Shift+Alt+-` for expanding and contracting, respectively. `Ctrl+W` selects the current word only.

Answer (score 11):

Expand:   `Alt + Shift + =`

Reverse: `Alt + Shift + -`

[taken from here](https://dailydotnettips.com/expand-selection-command-in-visual-studio-2017/)

Answer (score 9):

In ReSharper, this is *extend selection* and the shortcut is CTRL-W. Not sure of a non-ReSharper solution.

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio 2015 it's possible using a free "Hot Commands" extension:
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f073b573-c9a3-4104-a682-bd7a6c1023a6

Use "Expand selection" command.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xte2hh6a%28vs.71%29.aspx)) will select an entire word in Visual Studio. I cannot seem to find an option to select an entire code block.

Comment: @mr_ try Ctrl shift ] per http://dailydotnettips.com/2013/08/19/how-to-select-a-block-of-code-in-visual-studio/

Comment: Thanks :) - No joy (I am on C++ btw)

Comment: Ah and I am not interesting in selecting _an entire code block_. I want to expand the selection to enclosing element as detailed in the question. So caret > word > string > statement > block etc

Comment: It is still useful. If the cursor is at the beginning of a string, it selects the whole string. If it is at the beginning of a code block, it selects the whole code block. And so on.

Comment: Edit the shortcut to be `Edit.ExpandSelection` instead. Now standning on a letter and expanding the selection will expand to the word-ish.

Answer (score 1):

In the Visual Studio Menu Bar (Top) go to **`Tools > Options`**

Select **`Environment` > `Keyboard`** as shown below. 
[image]
Search for `SelectCurrentWord` and highlight the entry that comes up. Click the remove Button next to "Assignment".

Search for `WordNextExtend`, highlight the entry and add *CTRL + W* under "Press Shortcut Keys". Click the Assign button.

**Usage:**
move the cursor to any word, press *CTRL + Left* and subsequently consecutively *CTRL + W*.

That's it. There is a great benefit to using the same scheme as JetBrains Products. Enjoy!

Comment: while this seem similar, doesn't it only extends words to the right? (where as R# extends logical blocks)

Comment: That is true. It is not a total solution. Unfortunately there usually seems to be only a middle ground compared to the comfort offered by Jetbrains.

Comment: True, but what's the difference between this and simply CTRL+SHIFT+Right (or left). It'll extend the selection in that direction ... (and yes, comfort, that you pay for with money, and resources ... :) )

Comment: I agree, though Jetbrains is known to be really leniant towards Open Source and Academics/Students. The point is to let people know that this specific selection action is assignable to their liking - out of the box with a minor tradeoff. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This is build-in feature in Visual Studio 2017 (current version 15.8.1)

Expand selection to containing block
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>

Shrink selection to previous block
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>

Also you can expand/shrink selection progressively by

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> - Expand

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> - Shrink

Answer (score 0):

In addition to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left/Right Arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>+/-</kbd> mentioned in other answers here, there's also:

- Expand selection to line (`Edit.ExpandSelectionToEntireLine`) with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

I came here looking for the same thing in ***Visual Studio Code 2020 (v1.5.1.1)***. The answer is <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>right arrow</kbd> to expand or <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>left arrow</kbd> to decrease.