# Visual Studio Select All Inbetween Curly Brackets

Tags: json, visual-studio

I want to select inbetween of those two curly brackets. Any Solution on how to do it?

```
    {
      "name": "Pipit Farah shinta",
      "phone": "6283875566871"
    },
    "createdDate": "2022-09-04T13:49:09.215Z",
      "name": "Dani Mirta",
      "phone": "6281233213321"
    },
      "name": "Pipit Farah shinta",
      "phone2": "6283875566871",
    },
      "createdDate": "2022-09-02T17:31:17.538Z",
        "createdDate": "2021-02-03T10:44:55.613Z",
      }
    },
      "createdDate": "2021-04-06T06:28:33.511Z",
        "createdDate": "2021-02-03T10:44:55.613Z",
      }
    }
  },
  {
      "name": "Reza eprizaelani",
      "phone": "6283102288454"
    },
    "createdDate": "2022-09-04T13:44:53.386Z",
      "name": "Dani Mirta",
      "phone": "6281233213321"
    },
      "name": "Reza eprizaelani",
      "phone2": "6283102288454",
        "name": "ALDI OCTAVIAN",
        "phone2": "6281289172471",
      },
    },
      "createdDate": "2022-09-04T13:39:30.917Z",
        "createdDate": "2021-02-03T10:44:55.614Z",
      }
    },
      "createdDate": "2022-06-29T06:47:07.323Z",
        "createdDate": "2022-06-16T19:27:54.963Z",
      }
    }
  },
```

More like, I want to select only the "name" and "phone" only inside the curly brackets ( {} ) or delete everything outside of the curly brackets ( {} ) leaving only the "name" and "phone".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Go to Matching Brace in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501921/go-to-matching-brace-in-visual-studio)

Comment: @Helio , Sorry but that doesn't answer the questions. I want to select all codes inside the file that are inside a curly brackets.

Comment: first things first, show a valid JSON file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio editor - extend selection to the next larger code block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906593/visual-studio-editor-extend-selection-to-the-next-larger-code-block)